# Suggest correct data type to store user's birthday

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I need a way to `whatsUrBirthDay = Console.ReadLine();`

I could easily `string whatsUrBirthDay;` but I want to be able to store their birthday so that I can 'relatively' easily recall it later and possibly do calculations with it.

Is there such a data type that will allow for a specific format of MM/DD/YYYY? I assume I can ask for Month as a string, then look for matching spelling or numbers to = some variable afterward, but surely there's an easier way?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** I'd like to add that 'no', that is not the variable I'm choosing - just did it this way so you would understand what I'm asking for.

Comment: Correct datatype for this is `DateTime`

Comment: I am familiar with this, but it's very specific in the format that it accepts the Date, right?

So would I `catch` any entries that didn't match the obvious format or how does that work?

Answer (score 2):

Better you prompt the user to enter the date in some specific format, let it be `dd-MM-yyyy` and show an example as well So that you can validate the input and store to a DateTime variable; See the code below:

```
string myDateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
Console.WriteLine("Enter your Birth Date in the format {0} \n (example : {1}) : ",myDateFormat,DateTime.Today.ToString(myDateFormat));
DateTime userBirthday;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), myDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out userBirthday))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You lived {0} days from {1} ", (DateTime.Today - userBirthday).TotalDays, userBirthday.ToString(myDateFormat));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrongly formated input");
}
```

Note : if the input is not in desired format, then `TryParseExact` will returns false based on that we can show warning message

Comment: That's great! The CultureInfo.InvariantCulture has piqued my interest now. :) 

I have to ask, though, why did you create a variable just to store "dd-MM-yyyy" when you could have just typed it out in the WriteLine itself? Genuinely curious -- is this good habit or is this in case you needed it again in the future for other things, etc?

Comment: Sometimes I may use those formats several times in the code, to avoid repeated typing as well as typos I just used a variable to store that formats, You can read more from here about [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Reuse it like this? `Console.WriteLine("Enter your Birth Date in the format {0} \n (example : {1:" + myDateFormat + "}) : ",myDateFormat, new DateTime(1989, 02, 01));`

Comment: @un-lucky It is good but I guess the new born baby not know how to read yet :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the correct type for Dates is `DateTime`. You can achieve what you want using the [`Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)-method like that:

```
DateTime birthday = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out birthday);
```

DateTime also provides a [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)-Method which can be used to handle invalid input:

```
DateTime birthday;

// error handling similar to the following (if-clause work fine to)
while(!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine())) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, try again.");
}
```

If you are new to C# and want to know more about parsing dates/times, consider reading https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse which explains the most important aspects with simple examples (including error handling and such)

Comment: Thank you for answering. So the only way that it would be read/stored successfully is if the person typed it in the exact right format, yes?

And if they didn't, it would throw an exception?

Comment: either that or you handle it using `TryParse` like shown in my edit

Comment: Okay - your edit is exactly why I was reluctant to move forward with this. So the difference between TryParse and Parse is that one forces it while the other tries and throws a catchable exception if invalid?

Comment: `Parse` throws an Exception if the input was invalid, `TryParse` doesn't throw an Exception but returns `false` if the input was not valid. For user input, `TryParse might be what you want to use`

Comment: also, consider reading https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse which explains DateParsing quite succinct

Comment: AHHH, Okay. That makes total sense. Thank you so much. I know it was a simple question but I've been eyeballing that Data type and it just didn't seem right. It looks like my brain was at issue here. lol :)